# Irreversible Adiabatic Process

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

While studying about the entropy change of surroundings in irreversible adiabatic process, I came across a sentence.

> For infinite reservoir,  all processes are considered reversible

And suddenly it resumes with the equation:

q/T = dS (surrounding)

Can anyone explain the line and how the conclusion was drawn?

Comment: Can you provide a reference? What are you using as a convention for the sign of q?

Comment: Are you copying the equation verbatim? If using the convention that q>0 when heat is transferred from the system to the surroundings, then the equation makes sense.

Comment: q is the heat of the process. From the second law we know I know that q(rev)/T= dS. But to describe it for the surroundings only, the limitation reversible is removed. This is what I thought, but it just confuses me over.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating entropy change of surroundings](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/43183/calculating-entropy-change-of-surroundings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably find a partial answer in [this post](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/43183/calculating-entropy-change-of-surroundings). The reversible/irreversible tag refers to what is happening to the system, not the surroundings. Events in the surroundings are as a rule treated as reversible.

You should also keep in mind that heat is a signed quantity, and that there can be different conventions with regard to what is a positive/negative heat transfer. Usually chemists say q>0 when the system receives energy as heat, and when the surroundings *loses* energy as heat. Since heat is regarded as the sole source of change in the entropy of the surroundings (assumed to be an inifinitely large reservoir at constant T$^\ast$), we write $$dS_{surroundings} = -\frac{dq}{T}$$ for an infinitesimal heat transfer and $$\Delta S_{surroundings} = -\frac{q}{T}$$ for a finite heat transfer.

$^\ast$ An infinite reservoir can provide or accept energy in the form of heat without temperature change (or any other change in its state).